# Is it still factory method?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, factory-pattern

All examples which I found in general base on enumeration which provides to return the proper class. I need something which reacts in general on type of class and also is controlling constructors of new object by giving to it new parameters with each call.

Is it still factory method? Is it good solution? Can I play with design patterns in such way? Maybe there is better solution to provide?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  public abstract class Strategy
  {
    protected int Init;
    private static int _initA = 3;
    private static int _initB = 42;

    public static Strategy StrategyFactory(Strategy strategyType)
    {
      var tempStrategyA = strategyType as StrategyA;
      if (tempStrategyA != null)
      {
        _initA++;
        return new StrategyA(_initA);
      }

      var tempStrategyB = strategyType as StrategyB;
      if (tempStrategyB != null)
      {
        _initB = _initA * 2;
        return new StrategyB(_initB);
      }

      throw new ArgumentException();
    }
  }

  public class StrategyA : Strategy
  {
    public StrategyA(int init)
    {
      Init = init*2;
    }
  }

  public class StrategyB : Strategy
  {
    public StrategyB(int init)
    {
      Init = init*3;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While that is *technically* a factory method, it is combined with a good case of *ick*. Consider making the strategies themselves handle the strategy-specific action; while a type-specific dispatch is not always bad, it really has no place in this example.

Comment: ick? I have tried to seperate it and move this responsibility into strategies itself. But after many tries I failed and I found that it can be the best solution.

Comment: To me, it doesn't make sense for a factory to return the same type as what it accepts.  The only times I've used a factory method is to return a type that the caller does not know about.

Comment: Why do you need the factory at all? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Matthew But {playing the devil's advocate} the caller *doesn't* know about the concrete type here either (from a black-box view) nor is the caller responsible for creating the new instance.

Comment: This is a little too abstract.

Comment: Factory pattern is used to construct objects, but your factory needs an instance to construct new instance. How does the first instance will be created? Newed up? That defeats the purpose of factory. Doesn't makes much sense for me.

Comment: Yes. Sriram - it can also be called with `Type` parameter. The main problem is to controling creating classes with proper initalization parameters.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel But {being a devil's advocate} there is no restriction on what a factory method accepts. For the sake of argument (and since such is not provided) I propose that the objects were obtained from some external API; thus the last argument need not apply. (Although I do agree that it does not make much sense.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me what it looks like is you actually want to have a different factory for each strategy.  Factories are good if you want to either manage the lifetime of the objects the factory creates, or to manage dependencies / arguments for the construction of the various types.

**Definition of strategy factories**

```
interface IStrategyFactory
{
    public Strategy Create(int value);
}

class StrategyAFactory : IStrategyFactory
{
    public Strategy Create(int value)
    {
        return new StrategyA(value);
    }
}

class StrategyBFactory : IStrategyFactory
{
    public Strategy Create(int value)
    {
        return new StrategyB(value);
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
class MyController : ApiController
{
    private IStrategyFactory _factory;

    public MyController(IStrategyFactory factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int value)
    {
        // here we don't care what exact strategy is used, this is good!
        var strategy = _factory.Create(value);

        var newValue = strategy.Calculate();

        return new HttpResponseMessage(newValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or if all strategies are created the same way, use Matías Fidemraizer's answer (`Activator.CreateInstance`).

Comment: Ok, I will try this. I need constructors with parameters.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very strange factory method. See your factory method signature:

```
// "strategyType"? It's not a type, but an object reference
public static Strategy StrategyFactory(Strategy strategyType)
```

In .NET there's a class called `Type` which represents type metadata for some given type. You get it using `typeof` operator or `Object.GetType()` method.

Your factory method should be:

```
public static Strategy StrategyFactory(Type strategyType)
```

And you can instantiate a type using reflection:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(strategyType);
```

There's also a `CreateInstance` overload to [give constructor arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

### What about generics?

Since .NET 2.0 (we're talking about a lot of years ago!), .NET has *generics*. In summary, they provide a way to specify parameters which don't have a concrete type until a method or type is actually declared or used somewhere and provides which actual type will have the whole parameters.

For example, this would be a modern factory method:

```
// "where ..." is a generic constraint which defines that the given generic
// argument must be Strategy or a derived class of Strategy, and it must
// have a public parameterless constructor
public TStrategy Create<TStrategy>() where TStrategy : Strategy, new()
{
    TStrategy strategy = new TStrategy();

    // more stuff

    return strategy;
}
```

And now you can use it this way:

```
MyStrategy strategy = StrategyFactory.Create<MyStrategy>();
```

I could give you a generics' master class, but this goes out of the scope of your question. Anyway I gave you a clue/hint about how you need to build a factory using the right tool. [You can learn more about generics in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx).

Comment: @user2864740 And this is a very bad idea, isn't it? I mean, using the state of the instance... It's ugly